# Excel Formula referencing one column, counting variables in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for a formula that will count multiple variables while referencing another variable in a different column.

I have tried countif, countifs and sumproduct with no luck.

```
=countif('02'!$F2:$F:147="Y",'02'!H2:H147,"*PAR" or "NR")
```

Looking for a count of 2 based on the table below.

```
column f    column h    
N           NR    
Y           NR    
N           PAR    
Y           PAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of COUNTIF() should be COUNTIFS and it is not formatted properly.

```
=COUNTIFS('02'!$F2:$F:147,"Y",'02'!H2:H147,"*PAR")
```

to do the OR part you need to wrap the formula in SUM() and the parts in an array:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('02'!$F2:$F147,"Y",'02'!H2:H147,{"*PAR","NR"}))
```

[image]